# Parsing timestamps from data file and storing in vector

Tags: c++, parsing, timestamp, stdvector

I have some text-files with timestamps in the form yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss. 
I am creating a class and I would like a constructor that takes the name of a text-file and saves the times (not the dates) in a vector. I tried the following code, but my compiler complains when I try to create an object of this type (e.g. data test("file.txt")).

```
class data {
  vector<tm> timevec;
public:
  data (ifstream& in) {
  tm tt;
  while (in>>get_time(&tt,"%H:%M:%S"));
  timevec.push_back(tt);
}};
```

I am sure that there are several problems in my code above, but please be easy on me; I am completely new to c++.
As written above, my compiler complains when I try to create an object of this type - it says that there are no known conversion for the argument passed.

Comment: Is this a practice example in your C++ book? If so, this chapter should explain how to create objects, and how to invoke their constructors. If this is a homework assignment, it looks like you're missing some C++ fundamentals. It is true that `std::ifstream` is constructible from a string literal, but a mutable reference cannot bind to a temporary object, so you must construct the `std::ifstream` first, and only then pass the `std::ifstream` object to this constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hmm... Why are you saying this? `std::get_time` will read from any stream and parse output.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, or, alternatively, use rvalue reference.

Comment: I changed the constructor so it now takes the name of the file as a string. The constructor opens the file and inserts the data into another string. I now need to make it parse the data in the string and insert the time-data in the vector.
Sam: you are completely correct, I am definitely missing some fundamentals, but I am doing the best I can with the knowledge I currently possess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious why you are passing in the file stream when you said in the description that you wanted to pass the file name in to the constructor. Also, do you even need to bother with the tm type? Here is a simpler solution I think that matches the requirements:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class TimeData
{
 public:
    explicit TimeData(const string& filePath)
    {
        ifstream inFile(filePath);

        if (!inFile.is_open())
            exit(0);

        string date(""), time("");

        while (inFile >> date >> time)
        {
            times.push_back(time);
        }                       
    }

    void Print()
    {
        for (const auto& time : times)
            cout << time << endl;
    }

private:
    vector<string> times;
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<TimeData> td = make_unique<TimeData>("file.txt");
    td->Print();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I changed my code so the constructor takes a string (name of file) and opens the file. The constructor actually works now, I just need to parse the file and make the times go into a vector. I will go through the code you posted and see how I can use it in my code. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: My pleasure. I hope it is useful to you. Good luck!